# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities armv6 and armv7

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I snapshot my settings below.  In my project settings, i am targeting arm6 and 7.  Does this mean i need to include both armv6 and armv7 keys even though the descriptions by apple state "is compiled only for the armv6 instruction set":

armv6
Include this key if your application is compiled only for the armv6 instruction set. (iOS v3.1 and later.)

armv7
Include this key if your application is compiled only for the armv7 instruction set. (iOS v3.1 and later.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as you're compiling for both architectures, you don't require either of them. You would only include the requirement if you compiled for just one architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In xCode 4.2 it is not possible to switch the Architecture to armv6, Standard is armv7 and cannot be changed. I'm not sure whether the "armv6 armv7" value in the field "Valid Architectures" is enough for supporting all devices. Therefore I included the (array-)string value "armv6" as described by peterept in the key "UIRequiredDevicesCapabilities". I hope that like that my app will be compatible with all (iPhone) devices. 
Other experiences? Cheers.